# Is there a complexity class QPP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, quantum-computing, probabilistic-algorithms

The complexity class PP is not considered tractable, because the probability of success can get arbitrarily close to 50% from above as the problem instances get larger, so that (e.g. if this approach is exponentially fast) an infeasible number of repetitions may be required before we have a *significant* probability of confidently distinguishing satisfying inputs from non-satisfying ones. Nevertheless, PP is an interesting complexity class to study in its own right.

Is there a similar well-defined complexity class "QPP" of problems which a quantum computer has a greater than 50% chance of correctly solving in polynomial time? I understand that if so, this class of problems would not be feasible on a quantum computer, but are any nontrivial inclusions with the more "traditional" complexity classes either proven or suspected? How "big" do we think the class QPP is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yamakami showed in their paper [Analysis of Quantum Functions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9909012.pdf) that the quantum analog of PP is the same as classical PP. This is mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP_(complexity)#PQP) on PP.